# Adsense in web site. How to use and steps to follow

Tags: adsense

I want to launch the website, so what all the major and common thing I have to follow.

How to apply for AdSense so it'll get approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need original content above all and a lot
go here for more support https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense

Comment: Thanks it is very helpful...

Comment: no problem ;) @Ankit Modi